# Run same function simultaneously with different arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been attempting to make a small python program to monitor and return ping results from different servers. I have reached a point where pinging each device in the sequence has become inefficient and lacks performance. I want to continuously ping each one of my targets at the same time on my python.

What would the best approach to this be? Thanks for your time

```
def get_latency(ip_address, port):
    from tcp_latency import measure_latency
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    latency = str(measure_latency(host=ip_address, port=port, runs=1, timeout=1))[1:-1]
    #add to table and upload to database function()

ip_address_list = [('google.com', '80'), ('bing.com', '80')]


#Problem
#run function simultaneously but with different arguments
get_latency(ip_address_list[0][0], ip_address_list[0][1])
get_latency(ip_address_list[1][0], ip_address_list[1][1])
```

Comment: Look in to asynchronous programming or use a new thread for each target, you want to ping.

Comment: In addition to @AlexanderFalk comment, you may want to have a look at multiprocessing or threading packages, compare the following for the difference between them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python

Comment: I think this is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loop does not run in simultaneous.

You can use threading to run in simultaneous.

see this:

```
import threading

def get_latency(ip_address, port):
    from tcp_latency import measure_latency
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    latency = str(measure_latency(host=ip_address, port=port, runs=1, timeout=1))[1:-1]
    #add to table and upload to database function()

ip_address_list = [('google.com', '80'), ('bing.com', '80')]

#adding to thread

t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_latency, args=(ip_address_list[0][0], ip_address_list[0][1])) 

t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_latency, args=(ip_address_list[1][0], ip_address_list[1][1])) 

# starting thread 
t1.start() 
t2.start() 

# wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
t1.join() 
# wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
t2.join() 

# both threads completely executed 
print("Done!")
```

Comment: This is similar to what I am looking for, how would we be able to add a for loop to make the code support a variable amount of threads? Probably relying on len(ip_address_list)

Comment: loop over ip_address_list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop for this purpose.
Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(ip_address_list)):
    print(get_latency(ip_address_list[i][0], ip_address_list[i][1]))
```

Also you should define the modules before writing the function and return the results

```
from tcp_latency import measure_latency
from datetime import datetime

def get_latency(ip_address, port):
    .
    .
    .
    return results
```

Comment: This won't make anything simultaneously and therefore misses the question, which searches for some parallel solution.